# Gitlab-CI: How to use needs with parallel matrix (or another way to handle multi-step CI with needs)

Tags: gitlab, yaml, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a Gitlab-CI use case that I can't properly figure out. The background is that I have multiple environments that need to have their own artifacts built and deployed. Let's say a simplified case looks like this:

```
stages:
  - build
  - deploy

AppOne:Build:
  extends: .build
  environment:
    name: AppOne

AppOne:Deploy:
  extends: .deploy
  needs: ['AppOne:Build']
  environment:
    name: AppOne

AppTwo:Build:
  extends: .build
  environment:
    name: AppTwo

AppTwo:Deploy:
  extends: .deploy
  needs: ['AppTwo:Build']
  environment:
    name: AppTwo

.build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - build.sh

.deploy:
  stage: deploy
  when: manual
  script:
    - deploy.sh
```

The process above works, but as you can see it's kind of long and repetitious with two apps and super simple process. The real process has three stages and up to 20 apps. I would like to know if there's a better way to express this? The build processes are identical save for a variable (set in the environment).

I guess I mainly want to know if there's a better way to express the "needs" without repeating it for each app, i.e. the app needs to be built before it can be manually deployed. I could do `needs: ['${NAME}:Build']` but that requires the `$NAME:Build` step to actually exist.

Please help, oh collective wisdom of the Internet.

Comment: Are the apps each in their own git repository? Or are they all in the same repo?

Comment: @AdamMarshall They're in the same repo.

Comment: There is an open issue for this, https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/254821, which unfortunately is still currently OPEN...

Comment: Hi! Did you find some solution?

Comment: @Mikhail_Sam I did not. I've just split the definitions into multiple files, one per site and then import them:```include:\n
  - local: '/sites/staging/gitlab-ci.yml'```

Answer (score 5):

That might now (Q3 2023) be supported with [GitLab 16.3](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2023/08/22/gitlab-16-3-released/#use-the-needs-keyword-with-parallel-jobs) (August 2023):

> ### Use the needs keyword with parallel jobs
>
> The `needs` keyword is used to define dependency relationships between jobs. You can use the keyword to configure jobs to be dependent on specific earlier jobs instead of following stage ordering. When the dependent jobs complete, the job can start immediately, speeding up your pipeline.
>
> Previously, it was impossible to use the `needs` keyword to set [parallel matrix](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#parallelmatrix) jobs as dependent, but in this release, we have enabled the ability to use `needs` with parallel matrix jobs too.
>
> You can now define a flexible dependency relationship to parallel matrix jobs, which can help speed up your pipeline even more! The earlier your jobs can start, the earlier your pipeline can finish!
>
> [image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/16_3/needs.png -- Use the needs keyword with parallel jobs]
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#needsparallelmatrix) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/254821).