# Enabling parallel builds in Gitlab-CI

Tags: cmake, build, devops, gitlab-ci

Currently I have a pipeline that builds a C++ program currently like this:

```
build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - rm -rf .git/modules/docs .git/modules/libraries/fc ./docs ./libraries/fc
    - git submodule sync
    - git submodule update --init --recursive
    - rm -rf build
    - mkdir build
    - cd build
    - cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release ..
    - make -j$(nproc)
```

This build must still build, but I also would like to build this in parallel but with a different cmake option;
`cmake -DBOOST_ROOT="$BOOST_ROOT" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DBUILD_TESTNET=1`

I have read about the parallel option thats included in gitlab-ci, but haven't had success with incorporating this.

Any insight it greatly appreciated! Will update if solved prior to answers

Answer (score 2):

You need to have two jobs. [This article](https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2020/12/10/basics-of-gitlab-ci-updated/) has some good ideas of how to set it up.

Now, Gitlab infers dependencies and assumes that you want to run them in order, so if you add a `needs: []` list, it helps it build a graph. If you want two of them to run at the same time, then you remove their dependencies.

If you have something before this build, like a test or compare, you can use `needs: ["test"]` or `needs: ["prepare"]` or whatever jobs you want to run before this build step, but you can use `[]` to tell the CI no dependencies are needed and to run them as soon as possible.

```
build:
  stage: build
  needs: []
  script:
    - .. common stuff
    - cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release ..
    - make # I'd probably remove this in a CI situation -j$(nproc)

build2:
  stage: build
  needs: []
  script:
    - .. common stuff
    - cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release AND OTHER OPTIONS ..
    - make # I'd probably remove this in a CI situation -j$(nproc)
```

Comment: I understand, this just adds another job to the build stage though; but I want both of these to be both building at the same time; currently it just waits for build to finish, and then runs build2

Comment: You need two runners configured as each runner will only run one job at once, but two runners can run two jobs in parallel.

Comment: See also [GitLab 16.3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76956828/6309), Aug. 2023.

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of `parallel:matrix` jobs. This feature runs one job multiple times but with a different variables set each time.
In your case it would look similar to this:

```yaml
build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - rm -rf .git/modules/docs .git/modules/libraries/fc ./docs ./libraries/fc
    - git submodule sync
    - git submodule update --init --recursive
    - rm -rf build
    - mkdir build
    - cd build
    - cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=${DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}
    - make -j$(nproc)
  parallel:
    matrix:
      # Initial state of your job
      - DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE="Release .."
        # Other options...
      - DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release 
        DBOOST_ROOT="$BOOST_ROOT" 
        DBUILD_TESTNET=1
```

This technique assumes that your jobs use the same variable subset, but with different values for each execution.

You can find more info in the official [docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/c/yaml/#parallelmatrix) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70024721/10046524) is another example, docker builds in this scenario, but the principle should be clear.

Comment: Can you please expand on what you mean by variable subset?

Comment: With subset here I mean that both jobs of the of original question will use the same variables, but possibly with different values.